# How to save your data you've already loaded and processed in Google Colab notebook so you don't have to reload it everytime?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've read about 'pickle'-ing from the pickle library, but does that only save models you've trained and not the actual dataframe you've loaded into a variable from a massive csv file for instance?

Answer (score 2):

[This example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) has some examples of different ways to save and load data.

You can actually use `pickle` to save any Python object, including Pandas dataframes, however it's more usual to serialize using one of Pandas' methods `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`, `to_feather` etc.

I would probably recommend the option which uses the GCS command-line-tool which you can run from inside your notebook by prefixing with `!`

```
import pandas as pd
# Create a local file to upload.
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df.to_csv("/tmp/to_upload.txt")

# Copy the file to our new bucket.
# Full reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp
!gsutil cp /tmp/to_upload.txt gs://my-bucket/
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.